# Querying an array of objects in JSONB

Tags: sql, postgresql, jsonb

I have a table with a column of the data type JSONB. Each row in the column has a JSON that looks something like this:

```
[
  {
    "A":{
      "AA": "something",
      "AB": false
    }
  },
  {
    "B": {
      "BA":[
        {
          "BAAA": [1,2,3,4]
        },
        {
          "BABA": {
           .... 
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
]
```

Note: the JSON is a complete mess of lists and objects, and it has a total of 300 lines. Not my data but I am stuck with it. :(

I am using postgresql version 12

How would I write the following queries:

- Return all row that has the value of AB set to false.
- Return the values of BAAA is each row.

Comment: Do `AB` and `BAAA` always occur at the same path?

Comment: No, the JSON structure is not always the same. 
I will need to query something like : when [0]->A->"AB" = false

Comment: Your example is not a valid json. For instance, the `"B"` key cannot appear in an array without a surrounding object. Same goes for `[0].B.BA.BAA` and `[0].B.BA.BAB`. Please post a valid example. Having multiple "input -> output" would also be useful. Finally, could you specify your version of postgresql? Starting with postgresql 12 you can use jsonpath operators, which might be useful here.

Comment: @Marth apologies for the JSON screwup, its all fixed up now. I am using PostgreSQL version 12.  Not sure what you mean by "input -> output".

Comment: If it's not always the same, then how do you know at which level `AB` will be? Also: which Postgres version are you using?

Comment: Using Postgres version 12.  

All I can know for sure is that 'AB' will always be in 'A'. I was hoping this would work like a JSON parser when I can find 'A' and then 'AB' in 'A' and then the value of 'AB'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can find the AB = false rows with a JSON Path query:

```
select *
from test
where data @@ '$[*].A.AB == false'
```

If you don't know where exactly the key `AB` is located, you can use:

```
select *
from test
where data @@ '$[*].**.AB == false'
```

---

To display all elements from the array as rows, you can use:

```
select id, e.*
from test
  cross join jsonb_array_elements(jsonb_path_query_first(data, '$[*].B.BA.BAAA')) with ordinality as e(item, idx)
```

I include a column "id" as a placeholder for the primary key column, so that the source of the array element can be determined in the output.

[Online example](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=a33a0bf1d34bfe245077a4d852e1c249)

Comment: Thanks for that, it was super helpful.

Comment: How would I get the select query to return a string from the JSON. Ex: "select data @@ '$[0].A.AB' from test" returns t and f but if I try to run "select (data @@ '$[0].A.AA')
from test" I get null and null