# Trouble selecting text or numbers from a JSON stored in a postgresql DB

Tags: sql, postgresql, jsonb

This is a followup from this question I asked earlier: [Querying an array of objects in JSONB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65748940/querying-an-array-of-objects-in-jsonb)

I have a table with a column of the data type JSONB. Each row in the column has a JSON that looks something like this:

```
[
   {"A": {"AA": "something", "AB": false}},
   {"B": {"BA":[{"BAAA": [1,2,3,4]},{"BABA": {"one": 42}}]}}
]
```

Note: the JSON is a complete mess of lists and objects, and it has a total of 300 lines. Not my data but I am stuck with it. :(

I am using postgresql version 12

I am trying to write a query to return the value of AA (A->AA). This is the query I tried:

```
select data @@ '$[*].A.AA' from test
```

That just returns null.

But when I run this query:

```
select data @@ '$[*].A.AB' from test
```

It correctly returns false.

Question:

- Why does the query return a value when the return type is a boolean and return null when the return type is a text?
- How do I write a query to return text?

Some sample data to play with: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=fec0ba6e9bd6dffb9874e20ef7abab1d

Comment: The operator `@@` returns a boolean - it tests if the JSONPath expression exists. It does not return the value at that path. It's similar to an EXISTS condition in regular SQL

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are misunderstanding what the `@@` does. It checks if the JSONPath expression is true. It does not return the value at that path.

A path expression like `'$[*].A.AB'` does not really make sense for the `@@` operator as it does not contain any conditional operators like `==` or `<` or `>` that could be evaluated.

`'$[*].A.AB'` just happens to work because the value at that path is a boolean. If that was e.g. an integer, it would also [return null](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=a43863b6cf07e2bb71d3da4919da700b)

If you want to pick the value through a JSON path function, you need to use `jsonb_path_query_first()`

```
select jsonb_path_query_first(data, '$[*].A.AB') 
from test
```

Note that the result is again a JSONB value, not a `text` value. If you want it as `text` use `jsonb_path_query_first(data, '$[*].A.AB') #>> '{}'`

[dbFiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=0f7f7e7d53a70d6c1024fdf61d234c15)

---

It would indeed be nice if there was an operator like `#>` that accepts a JSONPath to extract the value at that path, but currently we have to live with the clumsy `jsonb_path_query_first()`